# Place frame when taking photo Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xamarin, jboss, iconic

I want to develop an application that takes a photograph and allows you to select a frame for photography.

I already have developed the interfaces, like taking the photo and storing it.

But I put a frame to the photo taken I could not.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what format do you store taken photos and your frame images? If you plan to insert your picture into a simple frame, I'd suggest to first draw your taken picture on a [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), and then draw your frame over it. Keep in mind the sizing - you don't want your picture be too small or too big.

I'm providing an example snippet here:

```
public Bitmap Output(Bitmap takenPhoto, Bitmap frameImage)
{        
    int width, height, x, y;
    height = ### // your desired height of the whole output image 
    width = ### // your desired width of the whole output image
    x = ### // specify indentation for the picture
    y = ###

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    c.drawBitmap(takenPhoto, x, y, paint); // draw your photo over canvas, keep indentation in mind (x and y)
    c.drawBitmap(frameImage, 0, 0, paint); // now draw your frame on top of the image

    return result;
}
```

Keep in mind that I have not tested the code and you might (actually, you'll have to) apply corrections.

Comment: Hello  --->The photo in jpej format and the frame in png -->The frame is simple --> I'll try the solution to see if it's feasible ..  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I put my solution :

ImageView Resultado;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bitmap miBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(miBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    c.drawBitmap(drawableToBitmap(R.mipmap.ic_launcher), 500, 500, paint); // draw your photo over canvas, keep indentation in mind (x and y)
    c.drawBitmap(drawableToBitmap(R.drawable.silver_frame), 0, 0, paint); // now draw your frame on top of the image

    Resultado.setImageBitmap(miBitmap);
}
public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(int imagen){
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), imagen);
}
```